# Contents inside a parent div expand beyond the width

Tags: html, css

I need your help.

It seems that my child divs, (the textarea and text) expand beyond the border:
[image]

This is the desired result:
[image]

Here is the HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
#one {
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#two {
    text-align: right;
}
#three {

}
#field {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="one">

    <div id="two">text to the right</div>
    <div id="three"><textarea id="field"></textarea>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Many good answers below. You may also see different behavior with the scrollbars between the browsers. Some include the scrollbar in the width, others don't.

Comment: #field width is 100% of #one + 1px left border + 1px right border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Borders and padding on `textarea` are your problem.

### Two choices

Both choices are related to textarea's CSS. And as you can see from code below I've also added relative positioning to `#one`, just to make sure it'll work in the context of your page, so textarea's width will actually be sized by this container.

1. set proper `box-sizing` so borders and padding will be included ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt2gh/)):

   ```
   #one {
       width: 800px;
       border: 1px solid red;
       position: relative;
   }
   #two {
       text-align: right;
   }
   #three {

   }
   #field {
       width: 100%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       /* let's also add these for cross-browser safety */
       border-width: 1px;
       padding: 2px;
   }
   ```
2. set `width` to less than 100% ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt2gh/1/))

   ```
   #one {
       width: 800px;
       border: 1px solid red;

   }
   #two {
       text-align: right;
   }
   #three {

   }
   #field {
       /* (1px border + 2px padding) × 2 for left and right side */
       width: calc(100% - 6px);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Borders and padding are added onto the width.**  since your width is 100% it adds the padding and border onto the field.

so if the width was 120px of 'one' it adds 2px for the borders and a few pixels for the padding.

if you subtract the some space off of 'three' you can achieve this.

```
#three {
    width:794px;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/AVwLQ/)

The following should work with most browsers as well.

```
#field {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Otherwise you can remove the border and padding from the textarea.  There are quite a few ways to do this to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it to go beyond the border is that, it is taking `border:2px;`

Answer (score 0):

You set `width: 100%` for the `#field` textarea. By default, a textarea also has non-zero values for `border` and `padding`. So after all your textarea is **800px** wide(inherited from `.three`) + **4px** border + **2px** border = **806px** all together (but it might differ slighty, depending on browser you use).
Modify CSS for `#field` to this

```
#field {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

I also set `margin: 0` just to be sure that some browsers won't have it set to non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

the classic box model adds up width with margin, padding and border.

In this case, set your textarea another way of calculating width, i.e. box-sizing to border-box (width is proper width, without margin, padding and border)

`#field {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}`

(you might add desired perfixes, -moz, -ms, -o…)